# Java "target type of lambda conversion must be an interface"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

I'm trying to use lambdas and streams in java but I'm quite new to it.
I got this error in IntelliJ "target type of lambda conversion must be an interface" when I try to make a lambda expression

```
List<Callable<SomeClass>> callList = prgll.stream()
                                          .map(p->(()->{return p.funct();} )) <--- Here I get error
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I suspect it's just Java's type inference not being quite smart enough.  Try

```
 .map(p -> (Callable<SomeClass>) () -> p.funct())
```

Answer (score 20):

[`Stream#map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is a [*typed*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) method, so you can explicitly specify the type:

```
 .<Callable<SomeClass>>map(p -> () -> p.funct())
```

or neater, use a method reference:

```
 .<Callable<SomeClass>>map(p -> p::funct)
```

Comment: This solution is better than type casting, because it will give a compile error instead of a runtime error if the types don't match.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using some other fluent API, make sure you're calling the right method:

Wrong (facepalm):

```java
Optional.ofNullable(something).orElse(() -> createObject());
```

Right:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(something).orElseGet(() -> createObject());
```